# Optional and in any order

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse an ISO 8601 duration with the following pattern I did:

```
P(\d+Y)?(\d+M)?(\d+D)?(\d+W)?T(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?
```

But the problem is it works  on `PT158M12S` but not on `PT12S158M`. Is it possible to make the groups after `P` and the groups after `T` be in any order?

Comment: Just permute them. There are 12 permutation for the part after P, and 6 permutations for the part after T.

Comment: What do you need the regex for?

Comment: @Bergi, I'd like to convert it into a human readable format.

Comment: Since it can permutes, you probably should write normal JavaScript to parse it...

Comment: I don't know how though.

Comment: For the record, it appears you are trying to parse an ISO 8601 duration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601#Durations

Comment: Might be worth specify it in the question then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
P(\d+[YMDW]){0,4}T(\d+[HMS]){0,3}
```

(shorter version of Rohit's answer)

However this does not prevent to repeat any group, e.g. `PT1M2M`. You will have to check that afterwards.

Comment: This will not prevent the repeated group, and that is why I deleted my answer.

Comment: repeated groups can be solved with a few lines of code, there's no need to make the regex overly complex or unreadable just to save a few lines of code.

Comment: I don't think a simple regex can do that anyway, at sometimes it is better to post-process the results of a regex match...

Answer (score 0):

Google's Closure library has a built-in function for parsing such ISO 8601 durations: [Interval.fromIsoString(duration)](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_date_Interval.html#goog.date.Interval.fromIsoString)